# Name of a college career

Tags: undergraduate, personal-name

At my school, we call a list of courses (or classes) a semester or a term - as in Spring 2014 semester that includes 5 classes.

I'm looking for a word that means "list of semesters", whether it has been completed or not, for the actual degree. I've heard this called an "undergraduate career", but I think that can get confused for one's actual employment career. Does anyone have another word for this that would specifically refer to their college career?

Comment: "coursework" is one possibility.

Comment: May that be a "syllabus"?

Comment: It would seem that "degree" is the word. But this really is a question about [elu.se]

Comment: curriculum? studies? plan of study?

Comment: @EnergyNumbers that's actually where I went first, and they deemed it most necessary for Academia. No one wants this question. :/

Answer (score 5):

I have always used the following words:

- Program - as in "our undergraduate finance program"
- Course - As in an "international finance master course": WARNING: This can be confused with an individual class/module

I would avoid the use of the word degree because it can be confused with the piece of paper one gets at the end. I would also avoid the use of coursework as it implies the subjects one will study. However, to be fair, I have heard both of those words used quite frequently and one fun thing about English is that it gets modified by common usage, even when that usage seems wrong to some of us - we must go with the flow.

Another reason to be cautious about using the word degree is the common separation, by some, between a certificate (short duration), a diploma (medium duration), and a degree (longer than the other two). Using the word degree could cause confusion to some who might be looking at a certificate or diploma program.

Comment: It may just be a difference in our separate areas/schools but I've always heard "course" used interchangeably with "class".

Comment: @NathanFrancy I do see that often is the case on this site so I have edited my answer to clarify.